# Improve performance on cell update

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a large dictionary jDict , in this example 2300 elements but others of 150,000+.
I am trying to add those element to rows of cells.
I am looping through the elements jAcct of the dictionary and adding them to a sheet in the same workbook: wksAccts, row by row.

```
    For Each jAcct In jDict("records")
        For intArrayCount = 0 To UBound(strColumnsArray)
            StartTime = Timer
                wksAccts.Cells(lngCount, intArrayCount + 1) = jAcct(strColumnsArray(intArrayCount))
            UpdateCellTime = UpdateCellTime + (Timer - StartTime)
        Next intArrayCount
        lngCount = lngCount + 1
    Next jAcct
```

In this example, it takes 5+ seconds in total processing for the one line surrounded by the timer.
By contract, the REST API returns the data in .35 seconds and I parse the json into the dictionary JDict in .25 seconds.

This is the offending line of code:

```
wksAccts.Cells(lngCount, intArrayCount + 1) = jAcct(strColumnsArray(intArrayCount))
```

I'm looking for a way to speed up the transfer of specific elements of the dictionary (named in the array strColumnsArray) into the cells.  After this process, I turn these cells into a table.  Would working with a table in memory first, and then committing that table to cells help?  If so, help on doing this would be appreciated.

Basically, is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Initial testing on putting the records into an ADO recordset then using .copyFromRecordset looks promising.  Will post results.

Answer (score 0):

.copyFromRecordset is WAY faster.  Even the 150,000 records now take .5 seconds.

Before the loop, setup the recordset:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Fields.Append "invoiceNo", adVarChar, 10, adFldMayBeNull
rs.Fields.Append "partNo", adVarChar, 30, adFldMayBeNull
rs.Fields.Append "invoiceDate", adDate, , adFldMayBeNull
rs.Fields.Append "orderQty", adDouble, , adFldMayBeNull
rs.Open
```

Replace the offending line of code with:

```
rs.Fields(strColumnsArray(intArrayCount)) = jAcct(strColumnsArray(intArrayCount))
```

At the end of the loop:

```
wksAccts.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

As I was writing my question, the thought came to me and I added it in at the end.  I find that taking to time to break down and simplify a question for others, I so often come to the answer myself.  I have a thousand questions sitting in my drafts folder that I never sent because by the time I broke it down enough to communicate it, the answer became clear.  Thanks Stack Exchange for... just being here. :)